# MDX TopPrice (max) for each group

Tags: group-by, mdx

I have a query like

```
SELECT 
 NON EMPTY 
{
[Measures].[ItemPrice]
}
 ON COLUMNS , 
 NON EMPTY 
[DimItemView].[ItemName].[ItemName]
*[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
*[DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].[CustomerName]
on rows

FROM [Model]
WHERE (
[DimCompanyView].[CompanyKey].&[smr],
[DimDateView].[Year].&[2017],
[DimCurrencyParam].[CurrencyCode].&[TL],
[DimItemView].[ItemKey].&[03001],--Filtered for single item, just for simplicity. Will be all ItemKey s 
[DimDateView].[MonthName].[All])
```

And the output is

[image]

Another query

```
WITH 
  SET [AllItems] AS [DimItemView].[ItemName].[ItemName]
  SET [AllMonths] AS [DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]

  SET [A] AS 
    Generate
    (
    {[AllItems]*[AllMonths] } AS s
     ,
       s.current*
        TopCount
        (
            [DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].[CustomerName]
            ,1
            ,[Measures].[ItemPrice]
        )
    )
SELECT 
  [Measures].[ItemPrice]
ON 0
 ,
[A] ON 1

FROM [Model]
WHERE (
[DimCompanyView].[CompanyKey].&[smr],
[DimDateView].[Year].&[2017],
[DimCurrencyParam].[CurrencyCode].&[TL],
[DimItemView].[ItemKey].&[03001], --Filtered for single item, just for simplicity. Will be all ItemKey s 
[DimDateView].[MonthName].[All])
```

And the output is

[image]

What I would like to achieve is Left join two result in a single query, but containing TopPrice for each row for the left result for corresponding group (ItemName and MonthOfYear). Desired output is like

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to calculate it once, I'd use the following code:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[GroupPrice] AS
([DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].[All],[Measures].[ItemPrice])

SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{
[Measures].[ItemPrice],
[Measures].[GroupPrice]
}
 ON COLUMNS , 
 NON EMPTY 
[DimItemView].[ItemName].[ItemName]
*[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
*[DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].[CustomerName]
on rows

FROM [Model]
WHERE (
[DimCompanyView].[CompanyKey].&[smr],
[DimDateView].[Year].&[2017],
[DimCurrencyParam].[CurrencyCode].&[TL],
[DimItemView].[ItemKey].&[03001],--Filtered for single item, just for simplicity. Will be all ItemKey s 
[DimDateView].[MonthName].[All])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but GroupPrice gives me exactly the group price, not top (max) of a given group. I have updated my post and did some modifications on last image to add results which comes from your query and  clarify my need.

Comment: What aggregation of ItemPrice measure?

Answer (score 0):

ItemPrice=ExwAmount/QtyKg

Actually below code is gives me expected results, but too slow. Any improvments?

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[GroupPrice] AS
max([DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].Members,[Measures].[ItemPrice])

SELECT 
NON EMPTY 
{
[Measures].[ItemPrice],
[Measures].[GroupPrice]
}
 ON COLUMNS , 
 NON EMPTY 
[DimItemView].[ItemName].[ItemName]
*[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
*[DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].[CustomerName]
having [Measures].[Fiili_Fiyat]<>0
on rows
```

Comment: MEMBER [Measures].[GroupPrice] AS
max([DimCustomerView].[CustomerName].[ALL].CHILDREN,[Measures].[ItemPrice]) is the way to go